# Why does XMLHttpRequest overwrite existing event?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have an event generated by a button click which sets off an XMLHttpRequest.  However, I discovered that the original event is set to null once the XMLHttpRequest is started. Why does this happen?  Is there some way to preserve the original event?

```js
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', handler);

function handler(e){
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var method = 'GET';
  var destination = 'example.com';
  req.open(method, destination);
  req.send();
  
  console.log(e.currentTarget) // shows <button></button>
  
  req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(e.currentTarget) // shows null!!! Why???
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <button id='start' type='button'>Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `e` is not defined at the function set as `onreadystatechange` handler. Define `e` as a parameter to the function `req.onreadystatechange = function(e /* define e here */){
    console.log(e.currentTarget)
  }`

Comment: But e is still within scope everywhere inside the handler function

Comment: inside `req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(e.currentTarget)
  }`
the scope of e changes although target property remain same if this is what you need

Comment: What does `e.target` log?

Comment: e.target is preserved.  e.currentTarget resolves to the XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @takinola  `null` appears to be derived from "When an event is created the attributes must be initialized to null." Have you considered filing an issue describing what occurred at the DOM Standard specification  https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-currenttarget?

Comment: I don't think its an xmlhttprequest thing because it happens with setTimeout as well

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
     function handler(e){
      const buttonEvent = e;
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var method = 'GET';
      var destination = 'example.com';
      req.open(method, destination);
      req.send();

      console.log(e.currentTarget) // shows correct current target

      req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        console.log(buttonEvent);
        console.log(buttonEvent.target) 
      }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I require a reference to the event not the current target.  Since Javascript copies Objects by reference, copying the object is not an option.  (I also tried cloning it without success)

Comment: buttonEvent.currentTarget -> null in this case

Comment: Bro get buttonEvent.target, not 'currentTarget' :)